# on.click not working after first click on dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically create a table full of links of 'actors', which allows to pull the actors information into a form to delete or update the row. The delete button only pops up when you select an actor.

I'm able to click a row, pull the information into the forms, and delete it on first try. However when I attempt to add a new 'Actor' and then delete it, or just delete an existing 2nd row, the button 'Delete Actor' doesn't work. It's only after the first successful delete does the button no longer work.

```
var addActor = function() {
    // Creates a table of links for each added actor  with an id based from # of actors
    $("#actorsTable").append("<tr><td><a href='' onclick='deleteActor(this)' class='update' data-idx='" + actors.length + "'>" + newActor.fName + " " + newActor.lName + "</a></td></tr> ");

    $(".update").off("click");
    $(".update").on("click", selectActor);
};


var deleteActor = function(e) {
    $("#deleteActor").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var row = e.parentNode.parentNode;
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        clearForm(actorForm);
        actorState("new");
    });
};
```

I'm new to jQuery/javascript, and I'm pretty sure its due to the change in DOM, but I just don't know what to change to make it work.

[Here is an Example](http://codepen.io/zzzian/pen/oxmzOE) of it in action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

var deleteActor = function(e) {

```
$("#deleteActor").unbind();
$("#deleteActor").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var row = e.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    clearForm(actorForm);
    actorState("new");
});
```

};

Here is the link for unbind.
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: This is what I needed. I was trying to use event delegation, but I couldn't get it to work, so I stopped trying to implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you're adding another click handler (in jQuery) within the click handler function run from the `onclick` attribute. You should use one method or the other, not both. To solve the problem in the simplest way, just remove the jQuery code from the `deleteActor()` function:

```
var deleteActor = function(e) {
    var row = e.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    clearForm(actorForm);
    actorState("new");
};
```

Comment: The issue with this is when I click on <a> in the table, its supposed to fill the objects from the table row into a form, which I'm then supposed to be able update or delete with a button click of either or. I'll mess around with it a bit, and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

when you add html dynamically you need to attach the event to the parent static element like so:

```
$("#actorsTable").on("click","a.update", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: I see what you're doing there, and it make sense alone, but I'm new to JS/jQuery, so I'm a bit lost as to where that is supposed to go, and if I'm supposed to be able to click the <a> in a table row, and the form is filled with the objects stored inside the row, I then need to be able to delete the row with a click of a button. I put your code inside the `deleteActor` function, and then called it inside 
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#deleteActor").click(function() {
        deleteActor();
    });` 
but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I'm thinking I change `#actorsTable` to `#deleteActor` the class or id of the button I want to use to delete the row?